# Scoring a survey in R (loop)

Tags: r, loops, survey

I'd like to create a new column (Survey_score) to this dataset that calculates the average of Question (Q1-Q4) for each ID. I suspect I need to loop through each ID, but I'm sorta new to R. Any tips?

| ID | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1 | 2 |
| 1 | Q2 | 2 |
| 1 | Q3 | 1 |
| 1 | Q4 | 4 |
| 2 | Q1 | 1 |
| 2 | Q2 | 2 |
| 2 | Q3 | 4 |
| 2 | Q4 | 2 |

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.  You may use `df <- transform(df, Survey_score = ave(Response, EmployeeId))` to add `Survey_score` as new column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using `dplyr`(I let Id as 1, 2, 3)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(EmployeeId) %>%
  summarize(n = mean(Response))

  EmployeeId     n
       <dbl> <dbl>
1          1  3.25
2          2  3.75
3          3  2.75
```